# C#: AccessViolationException from EmguCV when trying to retrieve frames

Tags: c#, emgucv, access-violation

I am trying to show live streams from 3 different cameras using EmguCV library.
The cameras are connected using VideoCapture class by passing corresponding index to the constructor.

```
VideoCapture _capture1 = new VideoCapture(0);
VideoCapture _capture2 = new VideoCapture(1);
VideoCapture _capture3 = new VideoCapture(2);
```

Each instance subscribes to the "ImageGrabbed" event and try to retrieve frame in the event handler.

```
_capture1.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
```

EventHandler:

```
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        if (_capture1!= null && _capture1.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Mat _frame = new Mat();
            _capture1.Retrieve(_frame, 0);
        }
    }
```

But occasionally, the _capture.Retrieve() method gives AccessViolationException.

**Exception Details:**

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled. Attempted to read or
>   write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory
>   is corrupt.

Anybody could explain what can cause this exception?

Comment: It would be more helpful for us to find the issues if you include the exception details

Comment: The exception says that "System.AccessViolationException was unhandled. Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing VideoCapture.API.DShow into VideoCapture's constructor instead of using default VideoCapture.API.Any value.